# if div:target change css of another div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a responsive mobile first navigation, trying to teach myself progressive enhancement.

What I want to do is target my #header by clicking a menu icon, and thus setting my #menu to height 100%. Basicly making it show on clicking the icon.

I tried the following:

```
#header:target #menu {
      height:100%;
}
```

Wich didn't work. Anyone got any suggestions on how to change the #menu height if the #header is targeted?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XUC4B/)

*Edit: Since I'm building this nav using progressive enhancement, I don't want to use any Jquery or JavaScript. The point is making it compatible with all devices before adding a next level of UX. So it needs to work WITHOUT jQuery/JavaScript*

```
<body id="home">

    <div class="wrapper">

        <header id="header">

            <h1 class="logo"><a href="">Nav</a></h1>
            <a href="#header"> <div id="nav_btn"> </div> </a>

        </header>

        <nav id="primary_nav">

            <ul id="menu">
                <li><a href="">Portfolio</a></li>           
                <li><a href="">About Me</a></li>            
                <li><a href="">Nonsense</a></li>            
                <li><a href="">Services</a></li>            
                <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>                     
            </ul>

        </nav><!--end primary_nav-->

    </div><!--end wrapper-->

</body>
```

Comment: We can't tell you how to target an element when you haven't given us any clue as to the structure of the markup.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the jsFiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#menu` is not a *descendant* of `#header` so you can't simply use a descendant selector.

It is the child of the next sibling of the `#header`

```
header#header:target + nav#primary_nav > ul#menu { }
```

Answer (score 1):

change the `href` of the button to `#home`

so the following

```
<a href="#header"> <div id="nav_btn"> </div> </a>
```

becomes

```
<a href="#home"> <div id="nav_btn"> </div> </a>
```

and use this css

```
#home:target #menu {
      height:100%;
}
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/axrwkr/6GHM9)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did at first. But it jumps past the header, and straight to the menu. Making the header slide out of the viewport. Wich wasn't very user friendly.

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm. I accepted Quentin's answer because he answered exactly what I was looking for. Your answer would be more practical though. So upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can do but not the way you are trying,

here is the example

```
http://jsfiddle.net/MarmeeK/svu5z/2/
```

and the selector will work like this

```
#div2{height:100px;width:100px;background:red}//original color is red
#link1:hover ~ #div2{background:green} on link hover div color become green
```

I am sure this will do for height also :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `#menu` is not a direct child of `#header`, so you should change this:

**HTML**

```
<a href="#menu"><div id="nav_btn"> </div></a>
```

**CSS**

```
#menu:target {
  height: 100%;
}
```

[working example](http://jsfiddle.net/XUC4B/2/)

Comment: Yea that's what I did at first. But it jumps past the header, and straight to the menu. Making the header slide out of the viewport. Wich wasn't very user friendly.

Comment: Well, that's pretty much an assumption for `:target`.